# Access spring environment in a separate servlet

Tags: spring, servlets, autowired

I have to port an old spring app with servlets to a spring boot app.

I have configured a java style configuration file for existing servlets but I am unable to pass the spring environment to them.

for example the java config looks like this (I have skipped the real mapping)

```
@Configuration
public class ServletConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean initServletRegistration() throws ServletException {
        ServletRegistrationBean bean = new ServletRegistrationBean();
        try {
            bean.setServlet(new InitServlet());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            NewLog.logError(this, "InitServlet threw an exception: " + e, e);
            throw new ServletException("InitServlet threw an exception: " + e);
        }
        bean.setUrlMappings(Arrays.asList("...."));
        bean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean testReceiveServiceServletRegistration() {
        ServletRegistrationBean bean = new ServletRegistrationBean();
        bean.setServlet(new TestReceiveServiceServlet());
        bean.setUrlMappings(Arrays.asList("...."));
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean insertIntoInputQueueServletRegistration() {
        ServletRegistrationBean bean = new ServletRegistrationBean();
        bean.setServlet(new InsertIntoInputQueueServlet());
        bean.setUrlMappings(Arrays.asList("...."));
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean nonCxfRedirectServletRegistration() {
        ServletRegistrationBean bean = new ServletRegistrationBean();
        bean.setServlet(new NonCxfRedirectServlet());
        bean.setUrlMappings(Arrays.asList(".....");
        return bean;
    }
```

then in the servlet I would like to inject the spring environment but I always get null for the env vairable

```
public class InitServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    public InitServlet() throws Exception {
    }
........
}
```

The servlets itself works ok If i debug them on the given url mappings they respond, I would just like to access the spring environment from them to get the data from application-X.properties depending on the given spring profile.

Comment: Register them as `@Bean` and don't construct them inside the method that produces the `ServletRegistrationBean`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring can inject only into Spring bean, you need to register `InitServlet` as a Bean in `ServletConfig` configuration class.